# Performance of non-indexed joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

Say there are two tables with these columns

```
FirstName Id
Joe       3
Sarah     5

LastName  Id
Smith     5
Rodriguez 3
```

and assume there are 3000 other names in each table which would match up if joined on `Id`. Also pretend that `Id` is not a primary key but just a regular integer column without an index or any other constraint.

Am I correct in assuming that the performance is O(n^2) for a join on `Id` without an index? Would MySQL create an index automatically for this join before performing it, recognizing how much more efficient that would be? I think in most cases it would be a clear win since O(n*log(n) + n) (sorting then iterating through each table) would beat O(n^2) for any non-trivial n. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: No. MySQL doesn't create indexes on the fly - it'd be a waste of time, and have to be performed EVERY time the query is executed. General rule of thumb is that ANY field used in a `where`, `join`, `order by`, or other "decision" type contexts should be indexed.

Comment: But if `n` were 3000 or some other large number, wouldn't it make sense to create an index first, even if temporary, since the runtime complexity of that boils down to O(n log n)?

Comment: Nope. Becausing indexing is an expensive operation, and re-running the index operation for every query would absolutely kill performance. especially if there's multiple of these queries in parallel. either all but one of the parallel queries wait for the temp index to be build, or they ALL start building their own private little idnex in parallel. indexing a table also forces it to be locked, so that the underlying dataset doesn't get changed while the index is "under construction".